# Validating Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimensions table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to validate TYPE 2 Slowly Changing Dimensions table, we had issue where new records are inserted into table but old records are not expired. That has been corrected. However I need to write SQL script to validate functionality of EXP column. Should I use CROSS APPLY and validate each column or there is better way to do it?

I have tried cross apply but not sure how to distinguish new vs old record.

If there are changes in data record for example for loan_no = 12345 with current exp max date '9999-12-31', that record would insert date under EXP column and new record would be inserted and EXP date for new record would have date of '9999-12-31'. I have to make sure this is happening for any changes and for those records where no changes are detected old record would stay with EXP date of '9999-12-31'

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general idea, you could use the `LAG` function to validate your changing SCD dates. Example (any records in the result set represent errors):

```
DECLARE @x table
(
    loan_no int NOT NULL
    , start date NOT NULL
    , [exp] date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @x
VALUES
(12345, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')
, (12345, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-28')
, (12345, '2019-03-01', '9999-12-31')
, (12345, '2019-04-01', '9999-12-31')

SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            loan_no
            , start
            , [exp]
            , LAG([exp], 1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, start)) OVER (PARTITION BY loan_no ORDER BY start) last_exp
        FROM @x
    ) Q
WHERE last_exp <> DATEADD(DAY, -1, start)
```

For the other scenario, to make sure you always have an `exp` date of '9999-12-31', you could use a simple `MAX` query:

```
SELECT loan_no
FROM @x
GROUP BY loan_no
HAVING MAX([exp]) <> '9999-12-31'
```

You could also have these in one query as something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            loan_no
            , start
            , [exp]
            , LAG([exp], 1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, start)) OVER (PARTITION BY loan_no ORDER BY start) last_exp
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loan_no ORDER BY start DESC) inverse
        FROM @x
    ) Q
WHERE
    last_exp <> DATEADD(DAY, -1, start)
    OR inverse = 1 AND [exp] <> '9999-12-31'
```

Comment: I actually just used a nearly identical query yesterday to correct an issue we had with invalid Effective Dates being populated. `LAG` was my friend. +1.